# How to change a structured array item size in Numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, recarray, structured-array

I am trying to change the size of an item in a Numpy structured array. The following code triggered an error saying the array can not be broadcasted because of the size difference. Is there a way to accomplish my goal short of making a new structured array?

```
import numpy as np

x = np.zeros(1, dtype=['value','f4',(2,3)])
x['value'][0] = np.random.rand(4,2)
```

Comment: I couldn't get your first line to work at all.  Did you mean this 
 
>>> x = np.zeros((2,3), dtype=[('value','f4')])

>>> x
array([[(0.0,), (0.0,), (0.0,)],
       [(0.0,), (0.0,), (0.0,)]], 
      dtype=[('value', '<f4')])
>>>

Comment: There might be parentheses missing in the `dtype` argument; perhaps it should be `x = np.zeros(1, dtype=[('value','f4',(2,3))])`.

Comment: @DanPatterson: Yes, I made a mistake. I meant to write what WarrenWeckesser wrote. Thank you both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the size or shape of fields in a structured array.  There may be a few values of the `dtype` that you can change (maybe names?).  But things that control the layout of the data, e.g. number of bytes per element, cannot be changed in place.  You need to create a new array, and transfer data (if possible).

Initially you are allocating a `(2,3)` array of floats to each element of x.  So the size of each is 6*4 ('f4') bytes.  Then you want to write a `(4,2)` array to the same slot, 8*4 bytes.  It can't fit.

The whole point to using `numpy` arrays is to define fixed sized objects, ones can be traversed in a multidimensional way quickly.

You could define:

```
x=np.zeros(1, dtype=[('value', object)])
```

Now you can write a `(2,3)` array to `x['value'][0]`, and then write a `(4,2)` array to.  `x` data just contains pointers to arrays, or other objects, that exist elsewhere in memory.

Better yet, use Python lists.

---

Looking at your original `x` with more elements might help

```
x=np.zeros(3, dtype=[('value', 'f4', (2,3))])
```

The (2,3) pattern is repeated:

```
array([([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],),
       ([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],),
       ([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],)], 
      dtype=[('value', '<f4', (2, 3))])
```

and if you look at just the field, you get a 3d array, 3 'rows' of (2,3) arrays is a (3,2,3) array

```
x['value'].shape
# (3, 2, 3)
```